# Why is "schism" preferred over "demur" in this sentence?

Tags: homework, gre

This is a verbal reasoning question in a GRE book. Obviously, the correct answer could only be A or B. And the explanation on the text book is "the correct answer is B".

> Unenlightened authoritarian managers rarely recognize a crucial reason for the low levels of serious conflict among members of democratically run work groups: a modicum of tolerance for dissent often prevents **__**.
>
> A. demur B. schism C. cooperation D. compliance E. shortsightedness

I know that *schism* does impose a stronger feeling, but I do not understand why I cannot choose A.

Comment: Why do you think *demur* would work in this context? Without that information, this borders on being *Not A Real Question*.

Comment: Probably because the test writers assumed that *demur* could only be a verb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Demur* as a noun is relatively uncommon, and I at least would consider it at least "dated". It means *a pause, hesitation*, but even that couldn't suit the context. Just my opinion, but I think the noun sense is rarely used except in the context of negation *(accept without demur, there shall be no demur, etc.)*

*Demur* is normally used as a verb today, meaning *to hesitate, object, prevaricate*. It's definitely *not* some "weaker" version of [schism](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=schism&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=BQmRTqCED4aZ8QPUpNw0&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ee0c22043ec7be3&biw=1427&bih=892) *a split between strongly opposed parties, caused by differences in opinion*.

In short, *schism* really is the only plausible candidate, regardless of whether the test writer forgot that *demur* can be used as a noun.

Comment: You've never done something *without demur*?

Comment: @TimLymington: To be honest, I don't think I have. I'd understand if someone else did, though I don't think I'd use it as a noun myself. But you're quite right - I'll tone down my assertion in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

*In this particular context*, 'demur' would probably mean something very like 'dissent', so it would be foolish at best, and contradictory at worst.

Answer (score -3):

I think choosing schism over demur has more to do with the first part of the sentence. Since two parts of the sentence are separated by a colon, the second part must signify the first part in the best way possible.

"Managers rarely recognize a crucial reason" is signified by "Modicum of tolerance". These two phrases are connected. Managers dont recognize a reason because they have tolerance.

Similarly, "conflict" and "dissent" relates to each other in a way. Isnt it?
The word in the blank must relate to "Members of the work group" in some way.
Demur(Hesitation) and Schism(Separation)...Which do you think can be associated in the best way...

Members' dissent can most likely lead to a separation "Among members of work group" in the first part of the sentence...What could possibly be the best thing associated...The members could separate as a result of dissent.."Demur" doesnt make sense here even if it was a noun because the two parts of the sentence must have connection.

If the sentence didnt have its first part, then "demur" would make sense. But the first part of the sentence gives us opportunity to rule out otherwise ambiguous options.

Comment: Hi Vivek, welcome to our site! Unfortunately I think there are a couple of problems with your answer. Firstly, it simply repeats the conclusion of the accepted answer (i.e. *demur* makes no sense here, *schism* is the only option that does). Second, your explanation is very hard to follow, and appears to be an explanation of the function of the colon. Lastly, your final paragraph is wrong: *demur* makes no sense in the second clause *regardless of the first clause*.